# How to fix "Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results" Xcode error?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, native, flutterflow

I'm trying to run my Flutter code natively on my iPhone, but whenever I try to run it, I keep get the following error message:

```
Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/matthewlee/flutterflow/AppName/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/ImageNotification.appex' to
'/Users/matthewlee/flutterflow/AppName/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex'
○ Target 'Runner' has compile command with input '/Users/matthewlee/flutterflow/AppName/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/matthewlee/flutterflow/AppName/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist'
```

I've been trying to rearrange my Build Phases in Xcode, but nothing has seemed to work yet. How do I fix this issue preventing my app from running?

Comment: You may refer to this link: Xcode 15: "Cycle inside ...; building could produce unreliable results" due to DSTROOT=/ - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730974?answerId=765092022#765092022

Answer (score 1):

i did 1st method didnt work and i did last one and worked for me. thxxxx

1st (Clean your project by selecting Product > Clean Build Folder from the Xcode menu bar.
Delete the DerivedData folder for your project. You can find this folder by selecting Xcode > Preferences from the menu bar, then clicking on the Locations tab. The DerivedData folder is listed under Derived Data.
Rebuild your project by selecting Product > Build from the Xcode menu bar.

After that

2nd.Drag the **Thin Binary** build phase to the bottom of the list. Rebuild your project by selecting Product > Build from the Xcode menu bar.